# Access values in double nested class

Tags: android, variables, variable-assignment, inner-classes

I have an issue while trying to get some values out of a anonymous class and assign them to the global variables `pDescr` and `pPrice`.

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] pDescr;
    private String[] pPrice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        ...

        iabHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        iabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {

            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

                // creating skuList here
                ...

                pDescr = new String[skuList.size()];
                pPrice = new String[skuList.size()];

                iabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < skuList.size(); i++) {
                            pDescr[i] = inv.getSkuDetails(skuList.get(i)).getDescription();
                            pPrice[i] = inv.getSkuDetails(skuList.get(i)).getPrice();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
...
```

I don't get any errors, but pDescr and pPrice stay always `null`. `inv.getSkuDetails(skuList.get(i)).getDescription();` and `inv.getSkuDetails(skuList.get(i)).getPrice();` are clearly returning strings.. I checked that though printing them to the log.

Where is my mistake?

Edit:

here is the code for the skuList, though it's not important

```
final ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < productsIDs.length; i++) {
       skuList.add(productsIDs[i]);
}
```

productIDs is an array with the ID's retrieved from a json. It has the correct values in it, double checked that.

Comment: have you tried to debug it inside the loop?

Comment: What is the value of `skuList.size()` ?

Comment: Show code where creating `skuList` List

Comment: `skuList.size()` is 5 in that case. When I log the values in the for loop I'll get printed out all the correct strings.

Comment: Can you post the full code to see the initializations? What exception do you get?

Comment: I found my issue, wanted to access the variable before the listener was triggered.. that's why it was null. Thanks for helping!